ROS2 windows installation without virtual machine issue
I am trying to install ROS2 on windows without using a virtual machine, following this guide. Everything seems to install alright until the last steps in the Setup environment section, where we call C:\dev\ros2_iron\local_setup.bat and run some demos to test if ROS2 is installed correctly. The terminal returns:
"[rti_connext_dds_cmake_module][warning] RTI Connext DDS environment script not found
 (\resource\scripts\rtisetenv_x64Win64VS2017.bat). RTI Connext DDS will not be available
 at runtime, unless you already configured PATH manually."

And no matter what command I tried relating to ros2, the terminal always returns
failed to create process

Even ros2 --help does not work.
I read somewhere that the bin folder in C:\dev\ros2_iron should contain a ros2.exe file? But I checked multiple releases of ROS2 Iron Irwini on their Github, and none of them contained this file.
I checked all the other dependencies (Python version 3.12.2, pip installs, Qt framework, PATH variables), and it seems to be alright. The problem is probably with the installation of ROS2 itself, since the ros2 command doesn't seem to be recognized
I'm seriously confused and lost after trying for hours. Hopefully someone can help me.
